# How to custom $watch in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to have a custom `$watch`.  This watch I will make on a variable.  I want when a the value of a variable is changed to see a message, and when the variable is not change his value to see another message.

An example is the next one: I have a textbox where I watch when a user writes something.  I want to see a message when he writes something and when stop to see another message.

Comment: did you try use a timer in your watch to check if the user stops editing the text box?

Comment: why you need a custom $watch? You just need to watch the model from the field. like <input ng-model="field" type="text"/>

Comment: i want to see a message when user stop to typing in text box

Comment: you can setup a timer, when the user writes give 1 sec and then display a message, if he keeps changing the text renew the timer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with a timeout:

```
$scope.$watch("myVar",
              function handleMyVarChange( newValue, oldValue ) {
                 //Change Display Message to Editing Message

                 //Timeout to checkif stop writing
                 $timeout(function (newValue) {
                 if(newValue === myVar) {
                   //Change Display Message to Not Editing Message
                }
               }, 100);
             }
);
```

Comment: Actually you should be doing that with events like onFocus and onBlur.

Comment: Agree with Miguel, it will be better to use onFocus/onBlur to change the message, unless you want to change the message even if the focus continue on the textBox.

Answer (score 0):

The concept I would recommend is called `debounce` in many javascript libraries. You give a function to call and a length of time that must pass without the function being called again before a callback is fired. Often times you can supply the option of firing the callback on the initial call as well. This would allow you to flip a switch on the first call, then flip it back once the amount of time has passed without the function being called again.

See: http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Ex:

(a better example would create a `debounce` service using `$timeout` eliminating the need for `$scope.$evalAsync()`)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  var toggle = debounce(function() {
    $scope.typing = !$scope.typing;
    $scope.$evalAsync();
  }, 500, true)

  $scope.$watch('name', toggle)
});

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this;
    var args    = arguments;
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

    if (callNow){
      func.apply(context, args);
    }

    function later() {
      timeout = null;
      func.apply(context, args);
    }
  };
}
```